# zend framework 2 - use global method

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

i need one function which i use in views, hydrator, some controllers and so on...
Where i can put it?

Where it would be the best add that can be maintained PHP OOP and zend 2 architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Create a Class that provides your funcitonality like `Stdlib\Godclass` and then simply call this class from your stuff. Sounds like something pretty fishy though, what would that function do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should be looking at the [Zend\ServiceManager](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html).  You can register factories (functions) and services in the service manager, and technically access them from anywhere in your application.  Your class would need to implement the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface in order to access the service manager, OR you would pass/inject the service into your class/model/hydrator/etc.